# How to login via ADFS to SharePoint via PowerShell CSOM

Tags: powershell, adfs

I cannot seem to remotely authenticate via a PowerShell script for a SharePoint 2013 on premise installation that is using ADFS and Windows auth for authentication. In my case, all Windows Users have a deny access policy on the web application level.  Is there a way to specify to login via ADFS instead of Windows auth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are a few solutions, but the [PnP-Sites-Core](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/SAML%20authentication.md) solution from Microsoft outlines exactly how to do this.

The solution is a bit long to post here, so I'll simply leave it as a link. You can find more solutions if you do a cursory search for 'CSOM +SAML'.

Comment: Thanks, you let me to this link, https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/ConnectPnPOnline.md that lets me do exactly what I'm trying to do in PowerShell.